# How to check if json array is empty in c#?

Tags: c#, json, google-maps, if-statement, system.json

I'm calling Google Maps and use System.JSON to parse the object. I grab my object using:

```
double placeLat = json["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"];
```

Then I want to check wheater the third objects exists and if yes perform some actions, but apparently the following fails. I know that Google Maps returns 2 objects in this case and I want to check for the third one to avoid performing actions on null and passing them further.. The following works fine when Google Maps returns 3 objects so I believe my condition is wrong.

```
if (json["results"][2] != null) {

        }
```

I get this error:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index

Any ideas of how to properly build the if statement in case using System.JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the results array only has two entries in it, then you can't access `json["results"][2]` because index 2 is outside the bounds of the array.

Before you access index 2, check `json["results"].Count` to make sure index 2 exists.  You might need to cast it to `JsonArray` before you access the Count.

Answer (score 6):

```
if(jsonobject.Count>0)
 {
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content);
                    var instituteDetails = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    **if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode && instituteDetails.Length>2)**
                    {
                        createModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<PaymentResponseDetailsModel>>(instituteDetails);
                        **if(createModel.Count()>0)**
                        {
                            return View(createModel);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("RegistrationInfo");
                        }
                       });                           
                    }
```

Comment: if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode && instituteDetails.Length>2)  and   if(createModel.Count()>0) worked fine  if you getting empty jsonstring and model .